# Нативный javascript (выборка)

Tags: javascript

Не могу повесить обработчик на input элементы формы, js нужно использовать только нативный.

Вот этот код видит только первый input, а нужны все, что есть в форме:

```
document.querySelector('.form-signin input').onblur = function () {
    alert('ef');
}
```

Comment: Верно.

> The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors. To return all the matches, use the querySelectorAll() method instead

Comment: пробовал =(

Comment: @Fikret, вы смотрели код? Пробовали убирать фокус с инпутов? Вам необходимо было использовать querySelectorAll заместо querySelector, который, как добавили выше, выбирает только первый элемент.

Comment: Пробовал, безрезультатно, вот Ваш код на jsfiddle мне помог, правда, начал работать, когда убрал это ">", т.е. вот так "('.form-signin input')"  
Если что, вот вся форма как есть: http://jsfiddle.net/w4pdxbpu  
В принципе пока все ок ;-)  
Спасибо

Comment: @Fikret, классный ответ получился!) Безрезультатно, но код помог =)
Символ ">" подразумевал что инпут идет сразу после обявления формы а поскольку у вас вложеность устроена по иному - скрипт не работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно, но попытаюсь предположить такой вариант http://jsfiddle.net/gr0uvhew/